# Gcoverage issue

Tags: googletest, gcov, gcovr

I have installed cygwin 3.3.5 version, I generated .gcno and gcda file. My gcc version is 11.4.0 and gcov version is 11.4.0, When I try to run coverage I am facing below issue. Can someone help 0on this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTdIB.png)

I need to get the coverage for my unit test cases.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy
the text and paste it into your question. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)